# ColdFusion : String : Get Price From Inside 2 Points

Tags: parsing, text, coldfusion, html-parsing

I'm playing with the NOMICS API and get data in a string.  But I'm having trouble getting just the Price:

This is part of the string from the METHOD=GET - which works fine..

> "currency":"SHIB","platform_currency":"ETH","price":"0.000026199726","price_date":"2022-02-06T00:00:00Z","price_timestamp":"

I know that ,"price":" is the lead and then "," is the end...
But I can't seem to get just the 0.000026199726 from the middle- which is what I need.

```
<CFHTTP METHOD="Get"
     URL="https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=#apikey#&ids=SHIB">

<cfset feedData = cfhttp.filecontent>

<cfset startpos = findNoCase(',"price":"', feedData)>
<cfset endpos = findNoCase('",', feedData)>
<cfset getdata = mid(feeddata,startpos,endpos-startpos)

<b>#getdata#</b> Errors as neg number.
```

The value of parameter 3 of the function Mid, which is now -191, must be a non-negative integer

This has to be an easy task.  I must be using the wrong string function?

EDIT: Figured out - it was finding the "," but they are so many of them it found first one, which put things negative - so fix was to find the structure after. ","price_date" is after.

```
      <cfset string = cfhttp.filecontent>
      <cfset startpos = findNoCase('price":"', string)>
      <cfset endpos = findNoCase('","price_date"', string)>
      <cfset detdata = mid(string,startpos,endpos-startpos)>

      <cfoutput>
          start: #startpos#<br>
          end: #endpos#<br>
          data: #detdata#<br>
          trimmed data: #trim(detdata)#<br>
          trimmed data: 
          <br><b>#removechars(detdata,1,8)#</b><br><br>
      </cfoutput>
```

I'll look at the JSON examples as well. Perhaps that will help with multiple pulls.

Excellent Folks : Thank you so much

```
      <CFHTTP METHOD="Get"
URL="https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=#apikey#&ids=SHIB,BTC">

      <cfset output = cfhttp.filecontent>
      <cfoutput>
      <cfset arrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(output)>
      <cfloop array="#arrayOfStructs#" index="getpr">
            <cfset Price = getpr.price />
            <cfset TKID = getpr.id />
            #tkid#: #price#<br>
      </cfloop>
      </cfoutput>
```

Spits out:

BTC: 43963.45841296

SHIB: 0.000033272664

Comment: Isn't the data from the API returned as JSON? Why not use deserializeJSON() function? Then just parse it.

Comment: Yep, like @AndreasRu said it's much easier than you're thinking.  Deserialize the `fileContent` string into a CF structure. Then you can access whatever keys you want by name, i.e. `theStructName.price` or `theStructName.currency`.  Also, don't forget to always verify the cfhttp response is 200 OK and contains valid json before doing anything with it or you'll end up scratching your head over weird errors later on.

Comment: In addition to the other comments suggesting using `deserializeJSON()`, I would also suggest using `precisionEvaluate()` to cast your string evaluation as a `BigDecimal` since your numeric calculation requires precision 12 digits after the decimal.

Comment: @user12031119 - Good spot on the precision!

Comment: Thank you all.  So much easier.  I had some old school XML custom tags. But this was far easier and now I can do lots with the data.  Thx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Andrea/SOS

```
  <CFHTTP METHOD="Get"
      URL="https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=#apikey#&ids=SHIB,BTC">

  <cfset output = cfhttp.filecontent>
  <cfoutput>
  <cfset arrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(output)>
  <cfloop array="#arrayOfStructs#" index="getpr">
        <cfset Price = getpr.price />
        <cfset TKID = getpr.id />
        #tkid#: #price#<br>
  </cfloop>
  </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks for submitting an answer to your question, and also for the credits :D !!! This will help others who are new to CFML.